# How to implement digital signature authentication in Docusign Rest API

Tags: java, docusignapi, digital-certificate, electronic-signature

We have integrated the DocuSign Rest API with Java application successfully and normal flow of document works fine. Now i need to integrate digital signature process. Is there any way of authentication by digital certificates.

Comment: Docusign provides the signature tabs which you can link with users who needs to sign it and can get response once he signs the document, also you can have different option like when to invalidate the sign and request again for signing the document. We have this with docusign. Reachout to your docusign support person.

Comment: I am using sandbox (Dev) account for integration. i couldn't find any signature tab for integrating digital certificate for user authentication.